# Iron Router 1.0 subscription issue

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, iron-router

Let me first say that I already put a post on on their issues board [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1006).

Since upgrading to 1.0.0 all of my subscriptions aren't actually hitting my publications.

In my router, I have

```
# Projects home page
Router.route "/projects", (->
  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe("projects")
  action: ->
    @render
  @render "projectsHome"
),
  name: "projectsHome"
```

Then on my server I have

```
# Publish the Projects to the user
Meteor.publish 'projects', () ->
  console.log "Getting projects"
  Projects.find({})
```

I don't know if I am not doing this properly, but my server is never actually logging `Getting projects`

Now, after the page is loaded using this code, I run `Meteor.subscribe("projects")` in the browser console and all of my data shows up and the server logs the proper line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CS syntax looks broken, try with this simpler example :

```
Router.route '/projects',
  name: 'projectsHome'
  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'projects'
```

Here is a variety of issues that could be the cause of your problem :

- Wrapping the second argument of Router.route in parenthesis is pointless, and this argument should not be a function in the first place.
- calling render in your overriding of action is useless : the default action is already rendering your template.
- beware of your CS indentation, the line `@render "projectsHome"` looks very broken in this regard.

Comment: Unfortunately, when trying this. I just get errors that say `pathFor couldn't find a route named "projectsHome". The way I set it up was taken from [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes)

Comment: Please post more code and account for `pathFor` new syntax which takes named parameters.